# Difficulty loading xstyle as a dojo dependency

Tags: javascript, dojo, amd

I am trying to create a simple customized widget using Dojo, and would like to load CSS using xstyle.  Looking at [the reference in github](https://github.com/kriszyp/xstyle), it says I can just add

```
<script src="dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async: true, deps:['xstyle/main']"></script>
```

and be done.  The problem is that I need to have xstyle already under my dojo modules, and I am not sure where to get / install it?

In summary, I have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var dojoConfig = {
                async: true,
                parseOnLoad: true,
                packages: [
                    {
                        name: "app",
                        location: location.pathname.replace(/\/[^/]+$/, "") + "/app"
                    }
                ],
                deps: ['xstyle/main']
            };
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/js/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```

and am getting the error `Cannot find .../app/js/xstyle/main.js`, which makes sense because I do not have it, and I do not know where to get it.

I downloaded the dojo install from the website, which includes dojo, dijit, dojox, & themes.  The CDN doesn't seem to have xstyle either.  I have also tried kriszyp's other method:

```
<script src="xstyle/xstyle.js"></script> <!-- or use the minified xstyle.min.js -->
```

to no avail.  I believe I get some `already defined` or `not defined` error depending if I add it before or after my dojo declaration.

Please let me know if you can point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

So after more looking into the issue, I found [this](http://odoe.net/blog/using-xstyle-arcgis-api-javascript/) blog post, which used [bower](https://bower.io/) to install xstyle.  After installing with bower (`bower install xstyle`), I was able to link to the xstyle package in the dojo config:

```
var dojoConfig = {
    async: true,
    parseOnLoad: true,
    packages: [
        {
            name: "app",
            location: location.pathname.replace(/\/[^/]+$/, "") + "/app"
        },
        {
            name: "xstyle",
            location: location.pathname.replace(/\/[^/]+$/, "") + "/app/bower_components/xstyle"
        },
   ]
};
```

This works, and I am successfully able to load CSS into my widget using `'xstyle/css!./css/checkboxTree.css'`.  I am not sure if this is the best way to do this, but it works.